# Symbolic Link Between USB and COM Port

Tags: usb, wine

I want to use a Windows based scan tool under Wine on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm [following these instructions](https://www.scantool.net/forum/index.php?topic=3086.0) to get it set up, but when I try to create the symbolic link ( step 7 ) I get an error:

```
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyS0
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/dev/ttyS0’: File exists
```

I want to access the USB device via a COM port like COM1.

[In the Wine documentation](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure), it says simply to make a direct link to the USB device:

```
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com2
```

Comment: You can't overwrite an existing (maybe virtual?) COM port (`ttyS0`). Try other numbers in increasing order until you find the first free name, e.g. `/dev/ttyS1`. I think that should help. If it does, tell me and I'll convert this to an answer, if not, also tell me and I'll try to think of something else.

Comment: @ByteCommander When I do an ls of /dev/tty* it seems that Ubuntu has automatically created 32 com ports, from 0 up to 31.  I think the program will probably only search the first 3 or 4 com ports.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you have a pre-existing device node called ttyS0 on your system. For example, I have:

```
[romano:/dev] % ls -l /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 oct 14 17:12 /dev/ttyS0
```

Giving the timestamp, the device is probably created by the `udev` daemon at boot.

If you do not have a real serial port / modem connected or you do not want to use it, nobody stops you from removing the device node:

```
rm /dev/ttyS0
```

(add the necessary `sudo`s around). After that, you can symlink `/dev/ttyUSB0` to it.

I *think* the node will be recreated at next boot; otherwise you can regenerate it (after deleting the symlink) with:

```
[romano:/dev] % sudo mknod /dev/ttyS0 c 4 64           
[romano:/dev] % sudo chown root.dialout /dev/ttyS0
[romano:/dev] % sudo chmod 660 /dev/ttyS0
[romano:/dev] % ls -l /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 oct 15 22:19 /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: Ubuntu seems to automatically create ttyS0 up to ttyS31 on every boot.  I deleted tty2 and created the link, but when I start the program under wine it doesn't see any com ports.

Comment: Be careful, `tty2` and `ttyS2` are different beasts (the latter should be COM3)

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes That is a different problem (if it's not only a typo in your comment, mixing up `tty2` and `ttyS2`). Please open a second question about making `/dev/ttyS*` COM ports visible to Wine applications. You should also accept this answer, as it solves the problem you first described. Maybe you want to edit your question after having written the second one to add a link to it though.

Comment: That's just a typo.   Having to manually recreate the link on every boot doesn't seem like a viable option.  Instead see the edit to my original question for what seems to be a viable solution.  Also See here for the new question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/686019/programs-under-wine-cant-see-com-ports