# Programs Under Wine Can't See COM Ports

Tags: wine

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I do an ls of `/dev/ttyS*` I see there are 32 ports automatically created by the system at boot up.  However when I start programs under Wine ( [instructions to install scantool.net under Wine](https://www.scantool.net/forum/index.php?topic=3086.0) ), they don't see any COM ports.

**EDIT**

According to [the Wine documentation](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure) all I need to do is create a symlink to the USB device.

```
lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices
International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

lsmod | grep ftdi
ftdi_sio               52885  0 
usbserial              45141  1 ftdi_sio

ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 אוק 16 07:21 /dev/ttyUSB0

ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1
ls -al ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sailorbob sailorbob   12 אוק 16 08:24 com1 -> /dev/ttyUSB0

sudo adduser sailorbob dialout
[sudo] password for sailorbob: 
Adding user `sailorbob' to group `dialout' ...
Adding user sailorbob to group dialout
Done.
```

OK, so it still doesn't show up under the scan tool in Wine.

**EDIT2**

So I tried running this command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a
stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: Device or resource busy
```

I'm not sure how it could be busy because the other end's not connected to anything.

**EDIT3**

Unplugged and replugged the scan tool and now I see the following:

```
~/.wine/dosdevices$ stty -F com1 -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 100; time = 2;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

However the scantool program under Wine still doesn't see the com port.

**As a diagnostic step, is there some way I can verify that the port is accessable via Wine?**

Comment: Might have an answer here: https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure

Comment: No luck, created a symlink like it says above and still doesn't see the com port.

Comment: Ickk, this says I need to create udev rules to give access to the device, surely there's a simpler way?  http://g8ogj.org/files/Using%20USB%20serial%20ports%20under%20wine%20howwto%20ipb.pdf

Comment: Did you try adding the user to the dialout group? -> `sudo adduser <username> dialout`

Comment: @EricCarvalho added myself to dialout and that didn't help.   Still can't see any com ports from the scan tool under Wine.